# External android compass

Tags: android

I recently bought a new android phone to get a bigger screen, thinking about using it for VR too. However, I found out it doesn't have a compass (I didn't even think it was mandatory). Even though I could probably live without VR, it bothers me when it comes to GPS maps, as they can't tell me where I'm looking at, and, most of all, Google Sky Map, which is pretty useful when I'm whith my telescope. Since I've seen lots of external cameras for android, even 3D and 180 degrees, and my phone does have OTG (I think it'd be needed), does an external usb compass for android exist?

Comment: Do you mean a GPS locator chip, or an actual North-South compass?

Comment: A magnetometer, which is needed to get the phone's orientation

Comment: The first thing to note is that your phone may well HAVE a compass, even if the stock firmware doesn't expose it. It may be worth looking into rooting the phone and installing a custom ROM to expose that hardware.

Comment: Also this is what you're looking for, but I'm not sure how to get it or use it. Some programming skill might be required, because it has that DIY aura: http://www.yoctopuce.com/EN/products/usb-position-sensors/yocto-3d

Comment: Thanks +Adam Wykes, but I think that the "to Pokemon GO users" part applies to me. I'm pretty sure it doesn't have a compass (Cubot Z100), it's new so I prefer not to root it